# Tizen nativ wearable development error Cannot find binary file(/Users/yvonne/CeBIT/CeBIT/Debug/cebit)

Tags: c, error-handling, tizen, tizen-native-app

I'm very new to Tizen and also to C. I want to develop a nativ Tizen app for the wearable Samsung Gear S2. I opened a Basic standard Projekt and wanted to run it on my watch. In the console was at the end the error: "Cannot find binary file(/Users/yvonne/worksspace/HelloW/Debug/hellow)". 
I found this file. It definitely exist.

Does anybody know why I get this error and why I can't lunch my app on my watch?
Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I can't say where the error does came from, but now it is fixed.

My colleague said, that it could be, because the clock used the WLan to be connected to my smartphone and not to the laptop, although Eclipse said it is connected. But thats only a theory.